# Filter Shadow for IE makes text thinner

Tags: html, css, fonts, filter, shadow

this filter 
`.ie8 {
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=1, Direction=0);
   font-weight: 400;
}`

makes text in my element

thinner and awful. It adds shadow though. Same with DropShadow. Strange thing that for element  everything works perfect. 
I wish I could post images.

How to make it looks right?

Comment: This is just the consequence of working with multiple browsers on multiple platforms. You should probably accept the limitations of `filter:` and either remove it for IE or accept its unattractiveness. IMO it's neither desirable nor necessary to make a page look *exactly* identical everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a rendering issue.  I've come across similar issues where a font will look fine in Safari/Chrome/FF on a Mac, but be too thin in Windows, especially IE.  It's not the best solution, but have you tried increasing the font-weight to compensate?  I would try increasing it to 800 or so for IE specifically.

Comment: yeah I've tried. still it looks terrible. I think it looks better for larger fonts, that's why my h1 looks prettier. but on that part font should be about 14px, so I'm sad. Without any shadow text looks much better in ie.

Comment: Then I would accept the shortcomings of IE (such as border-radius, damn them), and move on :)